# SQL- using CAST to convert from text to bit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with an error message that pops up when I execute the query below. I am using `SQL Server`

```
INSERT INTO table (code, Description, V21, V22, V23, V05,PYMNT, C_PYMNT, V22_PYMNT, V23_PYMNT, Rx_PYMNT, DatasetYear)
    SELECT Code, Description, V21, V22, null, V05, PYMNT, C_PYMNT, null, null, RxPYMNT, 2018 as DatasetYear
    FROM table a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Code, Description, V21, V22, V23, V05, PYMNT, null, V22_2019PYMNT, V23_2019PYMNT, Rx_2019PYMNT, 2019 as DatasetYear
    FROM table b
```

The error message say

> Operand type clash: text is incompatible with bit.

The columns that are in the "text" datatype are PYMNT, C_PYMNT, RxPYMNT, V22_2019PYMNT, V23_2019PYMNT, RxPYMNT.

How can I use "case when" to convert the datatypes from text to bit?

Comment: Can you please isolate the row and column (i.e., the precise item of data) causing the problem, and include it in your question? as well as the column definitions for the source and target tables?

Comment: @VictorDiLeo I edited the question and added which columns are formatted as a text datatype. Also, I tried using cast but that does not work so I need to use a "case when" statement with an rtrim

Comment: Please edit your question to include your table structure, sample data, and expected results.  See [ask] and [mcve] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what values you get into Text field but I hope this will help

```
SELECT CASE variable WHEN 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS variable
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation?